# A method to get JSON key values as a list

Tags: java, json

I have a requirement where in I have to get all the key values of a json returned now I am getting the json as a string.

```
String test = obj.returnJSON();
```

I need to get the JSON key values as a list is there any predefined method or I have just to write my own logic.

Thanks
KD

Comment: Go to json.org and pick from the roughly two dozen available JSON parsers for Java.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSON in Java library http://json.org/java/ or the google-gson library https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/. Either of these will parse the javascript string into an object, and you can get the keys from there.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Java [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) parser you could do it as

```
String test = obj.returnJSON();
JSONArray keys = new JSONObject(test).names();
System.out.println(keys.getString(0)); // key1
```

Answer (score 0):

the google library, GSON, is WAY BETTER and very useful.

I had the same problem and found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731215/get-key-names-from-json-object-using-gson)

Best regards!