# Gson parser class for Json response - Android

Tags: android, gson

i've  got response like below,

Sometime the language tag come with array value

```
{
    "name": "Tony",
    "id":"123",
    "language":["en","fr" ]
}
```

for some user the language value come with string value.

```
{
    "name": "Max",
    "id":"124",
    "language":"en"
}
```

How to create parser class to parse the json response using GSON?

Comment: is this a valid json?

Comment: It's not valid JSON, check it yourself: http://jsonlint.com/ Other than that, just check the gson documenation: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: @Raghunandan question updated.

Comment: @Blacklight the Questioner has put the details below the `JSON` actually it was 2 different JSON.

Comment: Look this post should be usefull for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731215/get-key-names-from-json-object-using-gson

Comment: you could parse with try and catch try if is an array and in catch manage it as a simple string

Comment: @Raghunandan yes this is a valid json formate. you can check from  [here](jsonviewer.stack.hu)

Comment: @bhaveshkaila it wasn't when i commented that was 31 minutes ago before it was edited again

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually this is not a valid JSON. The type of "language" should be determined for the very first moment.

If you are sending a list of languages in some cases, it is easy to send a list of ONE element in other cases.

```
{
   "name": "Max",
    "id":"124",
    "language":["en"]
}
```

On the other hand, if there is no way to solve this in the correct way you could use this workarround.

```
public class Model {
    private String name;
    private int id;
}

public class ModelWithLanguageString extends Model{
    private String language;
}
...
public class ModelWithLanguageArray extends Model{
    private List<String> language;
}
```

Then in your parser

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Model model;
try{
   model = gson.fromJson(response, ModelWithLanguageString.class);
}catch(JSONParserException e){
   model = gson.fromJson(response, ModelWithLanguageArray.class);
}
```

With this solution probably you have some casting problems along your code.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be direct answer, but you can **handle/achieve** this using **Jackson Parser** without any `try catch`. By setting **objectmapper** properties.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

Few other object mappers you should consiter setting,

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

**GetDetails.java**

```
package com.domain.project;

import java.util.List;

public class GetDetails{
    private String id;
    private List<String> language;
    private String name;

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List<String> getLanguage(){
        return this.language;
    }
    public void setLanguage(List<String> language){
        this.language = language;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Pass response for parsing.

`GetDetails mDetails = objectMapper.readValue(response, GetDetails.class)`

To get values.

```
String mName = mDetails.getName(); // Name
String id = mDetails.getId(); // ID

// Language 
int mLangSize = mDetails.getLanguage().size();
for (int i = 0; i < mLangSize; i++) {
    System.out.println("\nLang : " +  mDetails.getLanguage().get(i).toString());
}
```

The above will accept both **Array & String** in *language* key.

```
{
    "name": "Tony",
    "id":"123",
    "language":["en","fr" ]
}
```

.

```
{
    "name": "Tony",
    "id":"123",
    "language":"en"
}
```

Finally a small tip, Use http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/ to generate pojo classes, when there is an array inside array with few modifications, you can get all you pojo classes in a flash.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using GSON library then try this

```
public class ResponseBean implement serializable  {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("language")
    private List<Language> language;


    public class Language{

    @SerializedName("0")
    private String en;

    @SerializedName("1")
    private String fr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't the languages be dynamic? what would be case if there is any extra `ar`, `jp` comes?

Comment: THEN YOU HAVE TO WRITE LIKE  `@SerializedName("3")
    private String ar;` and `@SerializedName("4")
    private String jp;`

Comment: if 1000 Languages and all are dynamic?

Comment: for this you have to parse up to 1000 but if you will get only 4 value from response then that 4 values is store in variable other variable will return null value. i never try up to 1000 values.thanks;-)

Comment: You can handle this in `Jackson Parser` without writing `@SerializedName(x)`, just telling :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57005/discussion-between-bhavesh-kaila-and-venomvendor).