# Parsing JSON object using jackson

Tags: android, json, jackson

I am usin android built in parser but it is very slow. I want to use jackson but i am not able to understand hoe to perform same things with jackson as i did with android built it parser.

here is my code

```
String data = getArguments().getString("data");
    String RECCO_INFO = null;
    try {
        RECCO_INFO = getReccos(data);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONArray RECCO_ARRAY = new JSONArray();
    try {
        RECCO_ARRAY = new JSONArray(RECCO_INFO);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < RECCO_ARRAY.length(); i++) {
        try {

            JSONObject recco = RECCO_ARRAY.getJSONObject(i);
            String program = recco.getString("program");
            String outlet = recco.getString("outlet");
            String normalized_weight = recco.getString("normalized_weight");
            String distance = recco.getString("distance");
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String program_name = new JSONObject(program).getString("name");
            String outlet_basics = new JSONObject(outlet).getString("basics");
            String outlet_name = new JSONObject(outlet_basics).getString("name");
            map.put("program_name", program_name);
            map.put("outlet_name", outlet_name);
            map.put("normalized_weight", normalized_weight);
            map.put("distance", distance);

            oslist.add(map);
            list= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recco_list);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist, 
                    R.layout.recco_list_view, new String[] {"program_name","outlet_name", "normalized_weight", "distance"}, 
                    new int[]{R.id.program_name,R.id.outlet_name, R.id.normalized_weight, R.id.distance});
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return rootView;
}

public String getReccos (String data) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONObject info = json.getJSONObject("info");
    JSONObject RECCO = info.getJSONObject("RECCO");
    JSONArray RECCO_INFO = RECCO.getJSONArray("info");
    return RECCO_INFO.toString(1);      
}
```

Please anybody help me usin jackson, i have already downloaded jars. i have tried it seeing some examples but i am able to fully understand it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how slow is it? I'm parsing ~300KB of JSON and it takes way less than a second to parse, put it in List and create objects, and 2-3 more seconds to put it into DB.

Comment: It takes around a minute.

Comment: ~305KB I don't know why it is taking so long.

Comment: Are you running this on emulator or some very very low end device? Or maybe the fact that you parse JSON to String then parse that String as JSONObject and then again parse it as String?
Try something like this: `JSONObject program = recco.getJsonObject("program"); String program_name = program.getString("name");`

Comment: It worked but there's only a little difference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Create Getters and Setters for all the `key` in json.](http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/)
- Create an instance of [ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html).
- Configure the object mappers.

  ```
  objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
  objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
  objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
  objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
  ```
- pass the `response` and `class`.

  ```
  GetDetails mDetails = objectMapper.readValue(response, GetDetails.class)
  ```
- Starting getting the values.

[Here is a simple example for the OP's JSON.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650822/1008278) If you can post your JSON, I can post the code to parse and get all values.
[Here is one more example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709662/1008278)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is not the JSON parsing but these lines:

```
for(....){
    list= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recco_list);
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist, 
      R.layout.recco_list_view, new String[] {"program_name","outlet_name", "normalized_weight", "distance"}, 
      new int[]{R.id.program_name,R.id.outlet_name, R.id.normalized_weight, R.id.distance});
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

They are heavily unoptimised. All of this should be done outside the list, because you are creating/inflating them many many times. If you want the effect that items appear one by one, use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` method. Move them out and you will notice that performance improved many times.

Answer (score 0):

Well answering my own question.
I am using Gson to deserialise json into java POJO. it is quite simple and easy.
[This link](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/) will help.